# Disable etag Header in Express Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

We have a need to remove the `etag` header from all HTTP responses in our Node.js Express application.  We have a web services API written in Express where unexpected results are seen at the client when we send etags and the client sends back the `if-none-match` header.

We've tried `app.disable('etag')` and `res.removeHeader('etag')`, but neither work; the app sends the header regardless.

Is there any other means of disabling this header in all responses?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`app.disable('etag')` should work now, there has been a pull request merged to deal with this:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/610e172fcf9306bd5812bb2bae8904c23e0e8043

**UPDATE**: as Bigood pointed out in the comments the new way of doing things is the following

```
app.set('etag', false); // turn off
```

Change occured with version 3.9.0: https://github.com/strongloop/express/releases/tag/3.9.0

For more options on setting the etag check the 4.x docs here: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set

Comment: Is there a way to disable etags for only certain endpoints?  I don't want etags on my api endpoints but I do want etags on static content.

Comment: Doesn't work this way since 3.9.0 : https://github.com/strongloop/express/releases/tag/3.9.0

Comment: @Zambonilli posted how to fine tune for each endpoint w/o undocumented hacks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51694492/1737158

Comment: What express uses ETag for? Will anything go wrong if disabled?

Answer (score 29):

```
app.disable('etag')
```

This will disable etag header for all requests, but not for static contents. The following does it for static content:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
        etag: false
}));
```

Comment: This is important as it is easily forgotten

Comment: This isn't documented, but it also works for `res.sendFile('...', { etag: false })`. In my case, `app.disable('etag')` and `app.set('etag', false)` did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the express response.js, Etags are only sent when the request method is GET.
You can prevent express from sending etags in the response by setting the request.method to something else before calling response.send().

eg:

```
app.get('/path/returnsJSON', function(req, res){
/* HACK to workaround the framework sending e-tags and "304 NOT MODIFIED" responses */
req.method="NONE"; // was "GET"
res.status(200).send({data:1}); 
});
```

This worked OK for me.

Answer (score 3):

This sample works perfectly.

1. No undocumented hacks
2. Fine tuning for each endpoint
3. Can add/remove any header :)

   ```
   var onHeaders = require('on-headers')

   function myRoute(req, res) {
     scrubETag(res)
     // do the rest
     res.send('something')
   }

   function scrubETag(res) {
     onHeaders(res, function () {
       this.removeHeader('ETag')
     })
   }
   ```

Source: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2472

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I just requested some confirmation on that issue page ([#2472](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2472)) to see if this is still the same; so anybody reading this might want to monitor that page in case there's an update.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the real solution to your problem would be to figure out why it is behaving strangely due to the etags.

To answer your question though, Express does not currently have support for disabling the etags headers. It was actually discussed and merged [in this pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1421), but was later reverted. If you really need this and don't want to try to fix the root problem, you can always apply that patch and go from there.

Comment: Y! Slow suggests you remove etags.

Comment: I saw that pull request as well, but was hoping for a standard method that was supported by the framework rather than a modification that wouldn't be supported well in the future.

Comment: Looks like they ended up pulling it back in: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1694

Answer (score 1):

**You Can't using express**

You can only make them `false`, but that will still result in a 304 redirect because your etag will match the last request (which returned `false`)

**I used this solution from another npm package** (https://github.com/helmetjs/nocache/issues/9) which uses `on-headers` npm package to modify the header **after** express adds the etag.

This can be added anywhere you have your `res` being called, for a specific route or all routes:

```
const onHeaders = require('on-headers');

onHeaders(res, function () {
    this.removeHeader('etag');
});
```

**Note**, you may also need to change your cache settings. But this will remove your express etags :)

Comment: Are you sure? Matteo Collina mentioned that app.disable('etag') boosts performance in express, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gltzZjKYK1I&t=4m11s).

Comment: @LonnieBest from what I found I was sure, I can't comment on that talk though without further research, so it's up to others who stumble across this post to do their own research. However, I found that app.disable('etag') doesn't work, so not sure how the guy in the link got it to work :/