# How to disable caching for some routes in the Express 4 applications?

Tags: node.js, express, caching, etag

i tried these examples: [Removing all headers from express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740504/) this [Disable etag Header in Express Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191511/disable-etag-header-in-express-node-js) and this https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2472 but unfortunately they did not solve my problem. In Firefox, Opera and Chrome my app works fine when the developer tools are open and caching is disabled or when I start my app for the first time after browser was launched. I understand that this has to do with caching. Tell me please, how to disable caching for some routes in the Express application. Is it possible? Is there a general way to do this?

**P.S. I was very surprised, but my Express app works perfectly in Internet Explorer 11**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the headers to force revalidate by setting the `res` such as

```
res.setHeader('Surrogate-Control', 'no-store');
res.setHeader(
  'Cache-Control',
  'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate'
);
res.setHeader('Expires', '0');
```

or maybe a bit tidier with middleware

```
const dontCache = (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Surrogate-Control', 'no-store');
  res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate'
  );
  res.setHeader('Expires', '0');
  next();
};

app.get('/some-route', dontCache, async(req, res) => {
  ...
})
```