# ExpressJS ETag headers are not sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple ExpressJS app hosted on Glitch which returns array of posts.

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  
  const posts = [...] 
  
  res.json(posts);
  
});
```

When I use POSTMAN or ThunderClient (VS Extension) to make a request, I don't get ETag being returned in the response.

Am I missing something? I read that ETags are sent by default from ExpressJS routes.

Comment: They're generated by default, but it's possible 1. to [turn them off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191511/3001761); and 2. for something in-between Express and your client (e.g. Glitch's router) to drop them.

Comment: I can see an etag header in the response from [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/playful-automatic-sycamore). `curl -v https://playful-automatic-sycamore.glitch.me/posts`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Weird I have the same code but Glitch is not sending back etags.

Comment: Are there version differences in your express version in `package.json`?